# HP Pavilion g6 Notebook fan spins stops repeatedly

Tags: fan, hp-pavilion, fancontrol, noise, lm-sensors

My laptop fan is working annoyingly. It spins for 5 seconds and then stops for 2 seconds and then spins and then stops repeatedly. It always annoys me. I use sensors package to check when this happened. I realize when cpu temperature is low for example 50 to 55 degree it happens. I mean when cpu is working on a heavy process, then fan is working without stopping. There is no overheating issue at all. So you got the problem.

In the bois, there is only "fan always works" with yes or no options for fan control. There is no other option or information about the fan in the bois. Changing the option to yes or no has no effect on my problem.

Here is the output of sensors-detect

```
# sensors-detect revision 6284 (2015-05-31 14:00:33 +0200)
# System: Hewlett-Packard HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC [0696120000204210000610100] (laptop)
# Board: Hewlett-Packard 1670
# Kernel: 4.15.0-43-generic x86_64
# Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz (6/42/7)

This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
unless you know what you're doing.

Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): y
Module cpuid loaded successfully.
Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
Intel digital thermal sensor...                             Success!
    (driver `coretemp')
Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No

Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): y
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No

Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): y
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79' at 0x290...       No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D' at 0x290...                   No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D' at 0x290...                   No

Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
on some systems.
Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): y
Using driver `i2c-i801' for device 0000:00:1f.3: Intel Cougar Point (PCH)

Next adapter: SMBus I801 adapter at 4040 (i2c-0)
Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): y
Client found at address 0x50
Handled by driver `eeprom' (already loaded), chip type `eeprom'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)
Client found at address 0x52
Handled by driver `eeprom' (already loaded), chip type `eeprom'
    (note: this is probably NOT a sensor chip!)

Next adapter: i915 gmbus ssc (i2c-1)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus vga (i2c-2)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus panel (i2c-3)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y
Client found at address 0x28
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM78'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM79'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM80'...                No
Probing for `National Semiconductor LM96080'...             No
Probing for `Winbond W83781D'...                            No
Probing for `Winbond W83782D'...                            No
Probing for `Nuvoton NCT7802Y'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627HF'...                           No
Probing for `Winbond W83627EHF'...                          No
Probing for `Winbond W83627DHG/W83667HG/W83677HG'...        No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.1)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus AS99127F (rev.2)'...                      No
Probing for `Asus ASB100 Bach'...                           No
Probing for `Analog Devices ADM1029'...                     No
Probing for `ITE IT8712F'...                                No

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpc (i2c-4)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpb (i2c-5)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: i915 gmbus dpd (i2c-6)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y

Next adapter: DPDDC-B (i2c-7)
Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): y


Now follows a summary of the probes I have just done.
Just press ENTER to continue: y

Driver `coretemp':
  * Chip `Intel digital thermal sensor' (confidence: 9)

To load everything that is needed, add this to /etc/modules:
#----cut here----
# Chip drivers
coretemp
#----cut here----
If you have some drivers built into your kernel, the list above will
contain too many modules. Skip the appropriate ones!

Do you want to add these lines automatically to /etc/modules? (yes/NO)y
Successful!

Monitoring programs won't work until the needed modules are
loaded. You may want to run '/etc/init.d/kmod start'
to load them.

Unloading cpuid... OK
```

So friends, what is your suggestion to solve the issue?

Comment: My Dell E6530 running Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu 16) started doing this, I think it started maybe a month or two ago.  This was not customized for fancontrol, standard install.  It doesn't do it while in the docking station, but does it with a single HDMI plugged in (not sure if its related).

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu 16?  I recently upgraded to an Ubuntu 18 flavor and it stopped doing it.

Comment: I am on Kubuntu 18 which is based on Ubuntu 18 obviously. The problem is solved! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on Kubuntu 18 which is based on Ubuntu 18 obviously. I disassembled my laptop and noticed that the thermal grease is not covered the CPU surface efficiently. Also, my laptop fan was a little dusty. I cleaned that and assembled my laptop and then the problem is solved. Thank you all for your replies.